# mediawiki - parsoid http:401 log in required

Tags: node.js, windows-10, mediawiki, parsoid

I am trying to install visual plug in for my wiki.
during installation i marked nearly all plugins and the result is all available after start.

But i can not save a page via visual.

Because parsoid did not started after installation. 
So i decided to install parsoid my self via npm.

I started parsoid now the problem is: 
**Error contacting the Parsoid/RESTBase server (HTTP 401)**

at the same time on the parsoid termina i see the following lines:
**at Request._callback (C:\Users\baran\node_modules\parsoid\lib\mw\ApiRequest.js:332:35)\n    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\baran\node_modules\parsoid\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)\n    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)\n    at Request. (C:\Users\baran\node_modules\parsoid\node_modules\request\request.js:1157:10)\n    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)\n    at IncomingMessage. (C:\Users\baran\node_modules\parsoid\node_modules\request\request.js:1079:12)\n    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1327:12)
\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)","httpStatus":401,"levelPath":"fatal/request"},"msg":"Your
wiki requires a logged-in account to access the API.","time":"2020-11-17T16:21:29.965Z","v":0}**

So the critical line is:
**Your wiki requires a logged-in account to access the API**

I have installed wiki and parsoid separately how could i enable parsoid to login to the wiki ? ?

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the correct solution but it is possible to set wiki as "not private" so no need for login for parsoid, and you can protect pages that you don't want other users to modify.